# Escaping characters in JavaScript or PHP

Tags: javascript, php, escaping

I've been looking around a lot and tried different things, but how can I alert a string with special characters?

My code (in PHP):

```
echo "<td><a onClick=\"alert(" . $row['remarks']) . "\">LINK</a></td>";
```

How can I alert this variable:

```
$row['remarks']
```

when it contains characters like `(`, `)`, `;`, or others?

Things I tried:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-escape-string.php
- JavaScript's `unescape`
- others

Comment: `echo "<td><a onclick=\"alert('" . $row['remarks']) . "'\">LINK</a></td>";`

Comment: Unless your string contains quotes, all you seem to need is singlequotes inside the alert